# data in arraylist not displayed correctly. instead displays "System.Collections.ArrayList" - vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, arraylist

Can anyone please help, tell me why the data from database did not display in the rows? Instead "System.Collections.ArrayList" and "System.Data.DataRow" are displayed.

```
Dim myArray(4, 4) As String
For Each dtrow As DataRow In dt.Rows
  list.Add(dtrow)   
Next

For i = 0 To myArray.GetUpperBound(0)
  If i = 0 Then
    html.Append("<tr>")
  ElseIf (i > 0 And i < 5) Then
    html.Append("</tr>")
    html.Append("<tr>")
    For j = 0 To myArray.GetUpperBound(1) 
      Dim no = 0
         'insert the code i mentioned below here'   
      no += 1
    Next ' j'
  End If ' if in i'
 Next ' i
```

When i tried running using this 1 line below inserted to the above code, it displays System.Collections.ArrayList in the rows. 
`html.Append(list)`

But when i tried running using this 1 line below inserted to the above code, it displays System.Data.DataRow in the rows.
`html.Append(list(no))`

========================================================================

Another method i tried, when i tried running using this line "html.Append(dt.Rows.Item(0)(0))" , it displays the correct data, but when i tried to do a loop to increase the number of columns and rows, it shows the same value of data. as though as the 'rw' and 'col' loop didnt work.

```
 For j = 0 To myArray.GetUpperBound(1)
      Dim no = 0
      For rw = 0 To 5
        Dim rno = 0
        For col = 0 To 5
          Dim cno = 0
          no += 1
          html.Append(dt.Rows.Item(rno)(cno))
          cno += 1
        Next
       rno += 1
     Next
   Next 'j'
```

Comment: Answer is inside `html.Append` method, which you didn't show.   
Based on the output you get, obviously inside `html.Append` method you call `.ToString()` on the given parameter. By default `ToString`(if not overrides) will return name of the type - `System.Data.DataRow` for `DataRow`

Comment: The html.Append i got from this:
Dim html As New StringBuilder()

So what should i modify on my code to get it right? Which code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got a correct result when you used `html.Append(dt.Rows.Item(0)(0))` - now you need write correct loop.

Noticed that you have `DataTable` instance - use this for looping through all rows and columns

```vb
For Each row As DataRow in dt.Rows
    html.Append("<tr>")

    For Each column in dt.Columns
        html.Append("<td>")
        html.Append(row(column.Ordinal))
        html.Append("</td>")
    End For

    html.Append("</tr>")
End For
```

When working with `xml` I like using [LINQ to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx) with [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) type, with those I can be sure that my xml structure is correct during compiling.
Visual basic have a nice feature which c# does not - [XML Literals (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/bb384629.aspx)

```vb
Dim table As XElement = <table></table>

For Each row As DataRow in dt.Rows
    Dim tr As XElement = <tr></tr>

    For Each column in dt.Columns
        Dim td As XElement = <td></td>
        td.Value = row(column.Ordinal).ToString()

        tr.Add(td)
    End For

    table.Add(tr)
End For
```

Comment: td.Value = row(column.Index).ToString()

I tried running the program but error
"An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Public member 'Index' on type 'DataColumn' not found."

Comment: Good news: I can run it now. 
Bad news: nothing shows up on the page

Comment: You can debug and check if `html` or `table` objects contains properly generated data. If so, then you need check how you pass that data forward to the page

Comment: I searched and i found a sample showing that they created a .xml file. And then in the code behind file, refer the root destination to that .xml file in a function. Do i have to code this way too to display the data? Because later on, i actually have to link the database query to display the data rows in the table based on user's input from a dropdown list and a few textboxes then submit the page. Then supposedly the page will reload back with the data rows.

Comment: @Nurul, I think you need to create another question with sample code for generating data on the page

Comment: I tried putting your code into a function and return the values to the Page_Load sub, but it says value of type 'XElement' cannot be converted to 'DataTable'